# Rails f.select not passing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is code sample:

```
<%= form_for @article, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :keywords, class: 'col-md-1 control-label' %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= f.select :keywords, ['test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3', 'test_4', 'test_5'], {}, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => 'form-control' } %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

When I set multiple to 'false' it works just fine, but if I set it to true (for multiple select), it just doesn't pass any data. If I have verification it gives me an "keyword is empty" error and if I remove validation - it is just empty. Any ideas?

Comment: What exact data do you want to put into your keywords? Will it be some other model or do you want to go just with a plain text array for now?

Comment: Post the logs, let see what comes through in the params.

Comment: As output I just want a string with selected options ('test_1, test_2, test_5'), to later use it with scopes / sphinx.

Not sure how to get logs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.select :keywords, options_for_select([['test_1','test_1'], ['test_2','test_2'], ['test_3','test_3'], ['test_4','test_4'], ['test_5','test_5']]), {}, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => 'form-control' } %>
```

Comment: Changed to this, still getting "keyword can't be blank" error if I have verification on.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Tried new version, still same result

Comment: Go to your browser. Right click drop down. Hit 'inspect element' and paste please html code, that is generated on your page for this select

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
<div class="field_with_errors">
<input name="article[keywords][]" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
<div class="field_with_errors">
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" class="form-control" name="article[keywords][]" id="article_keywords">
<option value="test_1">test_1</option>
<option value="test_2">test_2</option>
<option value="test_3">test_3</option>
<option value="test_4">test_4</option>
<option value="test_5">test_5</option>
</select></div>
</div>

Comment: Everything works perfectly. Can you please also paste a controller action where you get this exception?

Comment: class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
 
  def new
    (a)article = Article.new
  end

 def create
    (a)article = Article.new(article_params)
 
    if (a)article.save
      redirect_to (a)article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :date, :src_url, :country, :author, :category, :keywords, :keywords2, :text)
    end
end

---- had to replace @ with (a)